# What logic and why is AppleScript applying to folder names? Guess what this script is doing

Tags: applescript, directory, finder

I just stumbled across one of the most awkward behaviours of a programming language in my live.

Guess what this AppleScript is doing:

```
set workspace to "tmp"
set folder1 to "08_0000012_11"
set folder2 to "8_12_11"

tell application "Finder"
    if (not (exists folder folder1 of (workspace as alias))) then
        make new folder at workspace as alias with properties {name:folder1}
    end if
    if (not (exists folder folder2 of (workspace as alias))) then
        make new folder at workspace as alias with properties {name:folder2}
    else
        log "Folder already exists " & folder2
    end if
end tell
```

It should create create two folders 08_0000012_11 and 8_12_11 inside the /tmp, right? ..... Wrong! It creates first one and claims the other one already exists. But it does not!

It seems that it tries to apply some logic to these names. Splits them into 3 numbers and ignores zeroes. Please tell me there is some reasonable explanation to this. Or this is happening only to me...

Comment: Same behavior for me. Not logic. To create folders, I use shell command 'mkdir' : much faster, does not create if already exists, and working properly !

Answer (score 0):

That's a bug in Finder. It should only ignore leading zeros when sorting file names, **not** when comparing them. [File a bug report.](http://bugreport.apple.com/)

The same logic works correctly in System Events, e.g.:

```
set fname to "001"
tell application "System Events"
  if not exists folder fname of desktop folder then
    make new folder at desktop folder with properties {name:fname}
  end if
end tell
```